# Can I pre-purchase more luggage allowance on Qatar Airways flights?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, bkk, arn, qatar-airways

Can I pre-purchase more luggage allowance on Qatar Airways flights?

I am traveling with Qatar Airways from Stockholm, Sweden (`ARN`) to Bangkok, Thailand (`BKK`) and I will be carrying one additional bag beyond the carry-on and standard check-in bag.

Am I able to pre-purchase allowance for this additional bag or is it always counted as excess luggage according to the fee list on their website?

And if so are there different rules for different routes (i.e transatlantic fares or such)?

Comment: I tried to pre purchase online from manage my booking a week earlier and I am unable to do it. I am waiting to be in that 96 to 12 hours time frame and see what happens.
I called the airline and told me to talk to cheapoair. I called cheapoair and told me to call the air line. I was so mad on cheapoair customer rep when he refered me back to the airline. Knowing I am not happy on his survice he suggested me to check with in 24 hrs of the flight. I just don't know if he suggested to let me just go from the phone or d trying to help really. I will wait and see

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So apparently Qatar Airways has multiple baggage [rules](http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/baggage.page). Some routes (to/from US, Canada, Brazil, Argentina) have rules based both on number of pieces and weight, as most other airlines (as far as I know).

In your case (travel between Europe and Asia via Doha), the baggage allowance is only based on the weight you carry. You are allowed 23 kg as checked-in bags, and as carry-on, [`One piece, not to exceed 7 kg and 50 x 37 x 25 cm`](http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/baggage.page). There are still usual rules for the maximum weight of a piece of luggage: 32 kg.

**EDIT** : as @JoErNanO commented, the rules changed (and price increased) for purchasing extra luggage allowance. The new rules follow.

To answer your first question, yes you can pre-purchase baggage allowance online, and [it is cheaper than at the airport](http://www.qatarairways.com/qa/en/excess-baggage-rates.page). You can purchase this extra allowance from the time you made the booking until 72 hours before the flight departure. 
The prices depend on origin and destination, for travels from Europe to Far East areas, the price is 40USD per kg if you book online.

You can also pre-purchase baggage allowance at Qatar Airways offices (in cities, airports, or via phone) but it will be the same price as when you check in (more expensive than online, by 5-15USD/kg). For travels from Europe to Far East areas, the price is 50USD per kg.

Note that for transatlantic flights (to/from Argentina, Brazil, Canada and the USA), the pricing is different. One extra piece of luggage will be billed 200USD per piece online or 250USD per piece in an office or at the check-in. The price is different if the piece of luggage weighs too much : 50/65USD per kg (online/office prices).

For those traveling to Africa, [there are bulk prices](http://www.qatarairways.com/qa/en/excess-baggage-bulk-rates.page). If you travel with more than 5kg extra, you pay a cheaper price (around 10USD per kg). This purchase can only be done in Qatar Airways city offices, though, at least 24 hours before flight departure.

Note: 1 kg is 2.2 lbs.

---

To summarize, you can book online extra weight allowance and [you will pay 40 USD per extra kg](http://www.qatarairways.com/qa/en/excess-baggage-rates.page) of baggage if you pre-purchase online at least 72 hours before your flight departure. If you just show up at the airport, you will pay 50USD per kg.

Comment: Does this mean I could bring two checked in bags at 10kg each and neither will cost extra as it total less than 23kg?

Comment: yes, apparently

Comment: Thanks for the research effort and confirmation of (some of) my suspicions Vince.

Comment: Vince, the extra luggage allowance can now be purchased online. See [the Qatar page on the matter](http://www.qatarairways.com/qa/en/excess-baggage-rates.page) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Yes on Qatar Airways you can pre-purchase luggage and in fact if you do it online Qatar offer you a discount from doing it over the phone or at the airport.

For their list of rates check out this page on the Qatar website - http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/excess-baggage-rates.page

If going from Europe to the Far East then it is $13 per kg if paid online or $17 per kg if paid at the airport.

Comment: I was not charged 17 USD when I paid at the airport. It was still the 13 USD per kg. I was not able to pay online in any way I could find out. For future travelers can you explain how one would go about using the website to pre-purchase luggage?

Comment: Alendri, having personally not done this I am unable to explain in detail how you would go about this. However, from the Qatar Airways website it would appear it is within the Manage My Booking area. There are some restrictions including that it must be done no later than 96 hours prior to departure. When did you attempt to do it?